# Invalid JS in Webpack 5 bundle. Some numbers from source code are replaced by numbers with letters. SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

After migrate from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5  I'm facing some problems.
Sometimes after building and running the app I get the error in devtools console like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

An error occurs in one of the chunks and prevents the application from starting.
After building the application some numbers from `node_modules` code are replaced by numbers with letters and the code becomes invalid JS.

This is an example of such a replacement:

```
.382683433 => .3a7f23433
590064 => 594c68
```

The problem has occurred several times. These actions helped to temporarily solve it:

- Removed `vendor` chunk
- Replaced `optimization.moduleIds` value from `deterministic` to `natural`
- Set `realContentHash` value to `false`

But after a few MRs, the problem recurred again and stopped the deployment process.

Disabling minimizing files doesn't help. Babel doesn't process these files.

The project uses:

- NodeJs v12.22.7
- Webpack v5.68.0
- Babel v7.16.0
- VueJs v2.6.14

My Webpack configuration:

```js
{
  mode: 'production',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  stats: 'errors-only',
  entry: './src/main.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash:4].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash:4].js')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': utils.resolve('src'),
      '@test': utils.resolve('test'),
    },
    fallback: {
      setImmediate: false,
      fs: false,
      dgram: false,
      net: false,
      tls: false,
      child_process: false,
      assert: require.resolve('assert'),
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
      constants: require.resolve('constants-browserify'),
      os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      util: require.resolve('util'),
      vm: require.resolve('vm-browserify')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        },
        include: [utils.resolve('node_modules/@ui-kit')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
              transformAssetUrls: {
                video: ['src', 'poster'],
                source: 'src',
                img: 'src',
                image: 'xlink:href'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          utils.resolve('src'),
          utils.resolve('test'),
          utils.resolve('node_modules/vuetify'),
          utils.resolve('node_modules/buffer')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        type: 'asset',
        generator: {
          filename: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[contenthash:7].[ext]')
        },
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024,
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        type: 'asset',
        generator: {
          filename: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[contenthash:7].[ext]')
        },
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024,
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [
          utils.resolve('node_modules/tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css'),
          utils.resolve('node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css')
        ],
        type: 'asset/source'
      },
      ...utils.styleLoaders({
        sourceMap: true,
        extract: true
      })
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        element: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](element-ui)[\\/]/,
          name: 'element',
          chunks: 'all',
          priority: 30
        },
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'initial',
          priority: 20
        },
        common: {
          name: 'common',
          chunks: 'async',
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: 10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    },
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin()
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
          to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
          globOptions: {
            ignore: ['.*'],
          }
        }
      ]
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash:4].css'),
      chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[chunkhash:4].css'),
      ignoreOrder: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
      }
    }),
    new RetryChunkLoadPlugin({
      cacheBust: `function() {
        return Date.now();
      }`,
      retryDelay: 1000,
      maxRetries: 3
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /ru/)
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `[contenthash:8]` here

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash:8].css'),
  chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[chunkhash:8].css'),
  ignoreOrder: true
}),
```